# unable to get data from firebase using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android

`this the format that I m trying to fetch
{
"-NN_ju1rbb8c3a-UHUnI": {
"messageText": "hello",
"messageTime": 1675670561048,
"messageUser": "Achal Chauhan"
},
"-NN_jvYFF5vfSPZVWcRv": {
"messageText": "how are you",
"messageTime": 1675670567216,
"messageUser": "Achal Chauhan"
},
"-NN_jwcgDz6-Rnk0h-lC": {
"messageText": "guys",
"messageTime": 1675670571660,
"messageUser": "Achal Chauhan"
}
}

//java code

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference messagesRef = database.getReference("chat-messages");
   // query=messagesRef.orderByChild("messageTime");
     options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(messageRef, ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.message)
            .build();
```

adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
@Override
protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull ChatMessage model, int position) {

```
                 Toast.makeText(MainChatActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                 TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                 TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
                 // Set their text
                 messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                 messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                 messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                         model.getMessageTime()));
             }
         };
    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue last week and better to use normal adapter and for new records you can use

adapter.insert(messgae)

and use this as a data class to convert messages from firebase

```
 val chat = ChatMessage()
 chat.set(dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String, Any?>)
```

add new object to list

```
 messages.add(chat)
```

then update your adapter

```
data class ChatMessage(
var messageTime:String?=null,
var messageUser:String?=null,
var messageText:String?=null,
){
    fun set(data: HashMap<String, Any?>){
        data?.let {
        this.messageUser = data["messageUser"] as String
        this.messageTime= data["messageTime"] as String
        this.messageText= data["messageText"] as String
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: if you need adapter code let me know

Comment: thankyou for the answer , I solved it too by using a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the custom adapter and `addValueEventListener`:

below is the code to get data from firebase:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference messagesRef = database.getReference("chat-messages");
    messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<ChatMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                messages.add(childSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class));
            }

           listOfMessages.setAdapter(new 
        ChatMessageAdapter(MainChatActivity.this, R.layout.message, messages));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```